# How can i add a placeholder which is a transparent PNG with white graphics, in every div

Tags: html, css, image, placeholder

Yuo can see i added a png img which is a transparent PNG with white graphics, and since is white i had to color the div but i cant see the img pls help.
i was searching on the internet but couldn't find anything.
I need to set my paragraf's and h1 to be repsponsive as well.

```
      
           .row{
               width: 90%;
               max-width: 960px;
               margin: 0 auto;
               height: 160px;
           }

           .row::after{
               content:'';
               display: block;
               clear: left;
           }

           .column{
               float: left;
               width: 16.666%;
               box-sizing: border-box;
               padding: 8px;
               height: 160px;
               margin-left: 20px;
           }
           .box{
               height: 120px;
               background-color: rgba(37, 122, 192, 0.664);
               background-image: url(placeholder-image.png);
               border-top-left-radius: 15%;
               border-top-right-radius: 15%;
               content :attr(data-placeholder)
           }
           h1{
               width: 90%;
               max-width: 960px;
               margin-left: 220px;
           }


           @media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
               .column{
                   width: 23.33%;
               }
               
           }

           @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
               .column{
                   width: 40%;
               }
           }

           @media screen and (max-width: 414px){
               .column{
                   width: 100%;
               }
           }
       </style>

  
  <body>
       <h1>Galery heading</h1>
       <div class="row">
       <div class="column">
           <div class="box"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="column">
           <div class="box"></div>
       </div>
```

Comment: If you look in your browser dev tools console are there any warning or error messages? It looks as though your image cannot be found - is it on the same directory? Are you trying to run this locally? Also what do you expect to happen with the content: in the .box declaration? Should it be in a pseudo element?.

Answer (score 0):

You have to surround the URL of the placeholder image with `"` (quotations)

Working example:

```css
.row{
               width: 90%;
               max-width: 960px;
               margin: 0 auto;
               height: 160px;
           }

           .row::after{
               content:'';
               display: block;
               clear: left;
           }

           .column{
               float: left;
               width: 16.666%;
               box-sizing: border-box;
               padding: 8px;
               height: 160px;
               margin-left: 20px;
           }
           .box{
               height: 120px;
               background-color: rgba(37, 122, 192, 0.664);
               background-image: url("https://www.bennettig.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/square-placeholder.jpg");
               background-size:contain;
               border-top-left-radius: 15%;
               border-top-right-radius: 15%;
               content :attr(data-placeholder)
           }
           h1{
               width: 90%;
               max-width: 960px;
               margin-left: 220px;
           }


           @media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
               .column{
                   width: 23.33%;
               }
               
           }

           @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
               .column{
                   width: 40%;
               }
           }

           @media screen and (max-width: 414px){
               .column{
                   width: 100%;
               }
           }
```

```html
<html>
<head>

  </head>
  <body>
       <h1>Galery heading</h1>
       <div class="row">
       <div class="column">
           <div class="box"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="column">
           <div class="box"></div>
       </div></body>
       </html>
```

In your case (you won't see the images in the snippet because `placeholder-image.png` doesn't exist):

```css
           .row{
               width: 90%;
               max-width: 960px;
               margin: 0 auto;
               height: 160px;
           }

           .row::after{
               content:'';
               display: block;
               clear: left;
           }

           .column{
               float: left;
               width: 16.666%;
               box-sizing: border-box;
               padding: 8px;
               height: 160px;
               margin-left: 20px;
           }
           .box{
               height: 120px;
               background-color: rgba(37, 122, 192, 0.664);
               background-image: url("placeholder-image.png");
               border-top-left-radius: 15%;
               border-top-right-radius: 15%;
               content :attr(data-placeholder)
           }
           h1{
               width: 90%;
               max-width: 960px;
               margin-left: 220px;
           }


           @media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
               .column{
                   width: 23.33%;
               }
               
           }

           @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
               .column{
                   width: 40%;
               }
           }

           @media screen and (max-width: 414px){
               .column{
                   width: 100%;
               }
           }
```

```html
<html>
<head>

  </head>
  <body>
       <h1>Galery heading</h1>
       <div class="row">
       <div class="column">
           <div class="box"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="column">
           <div class="box"></div>
       </div></body>
       </html>
```

Comment: Are you sure the quotes around the url are needed? I had not heard that before.